# How to check Offset left value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make something happen when my element has moved a certain left amount.

```
var box = $('#box');    
box.css('left', '500px'); //This is moving the box. I have a transition set in my css
if (box.offset().left == 200){
    alert("yes");
}
```

It doesn't alert yes, though. I tried outputting the offset().left position into the console, and it DOES reach 200. Am I just using inproper syntax?

Comment: Did you mean to do if (box.offset().left >= 200)?

Comment: @Nate Nope, I want something to happen once it reaches the 200 mark.

Answer (score 1):

Using `elem.css('left','500px')` will set the left of the element to *500px*. As you are comparing with `200`, it will never meet that condition. Even in the soultion provided below, you still con not reallt compare it with single value as the progress will never be one pixle at a time. In provided solution, range of *200 - 250* is given.

> Use [`progress`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) option of [`jQuery animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Try this:

```js
var box = $('#box');
var datatDiv = $('#data');
box.animate({
  'left': '500px'
}, {
  duration: 5000,
  progress: function() {
    var leftVal = box.offset().left
    if (leftVal > 200 && leftVal < 250) {
      datatDiv.text("YES");
    } else {
      datatDiv.text("NO");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#box {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">BOX</div>
<br>
<div id='data'></div>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/cd8tLs0q/1/)

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately the result is not as smooth as if I use CSS. I'm trying to run a sort of side scroller game, so I need it to be smooth.

Comment: I was able to do it with jQuery's position function.

Comment: I am not sure about your requirement. Can you share your code ?

Comment: I was able to get what I needed from the position() function, but unfortunately I am using setInterval to keep an eye on it, and it's slowing down my site. Basically, I have a background image with trees that keeps moving to the left. You control a ball that has to jump over the trees.

// CHECK TO SEE IF HIT TREE
var snowballInterval = setInterval(function(){
 //1
 if(
 (sideScroller.position().left < -960 
 && sideScroller.position().left > -1200 + mobileDelay)
 && (snowball.css('bottom') == '75px')
 ){hitTree()} 
 //2
 else if...
Continued in next comment...

Comment: So basically all this is doing is checking to see if the ball hit the tree, and then if it does execute the hitTree function. This is all working fine, but if you know of a better way to keep an eye on the position rather than setInterval, I would love to know it.

Comment: Read about _Request Animation Frame_

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish what I needed through the position() function. I have a side scrolling image that moves to the left, and you control a snowball that must hop over trees. I needed to detect when the image had moved a certain distance to the left, which meant it collided with a tree in the image.

```js
 if (
   (sideScroller.position().left < -960 && sideScroller.position().left > -1200 + mobileDelay) && (snowball.css('bottom') == '75px')
 ) {
   hitTree()
 }
```

mobileDelay was just some additional value for mobile devices, and hit tree just caused the snowball to evaporate when it hits a tree, lol. Position() works like a charm here.

I would just like to point out that Rayon's answer works as well, however I personally prefer to leave as much animation to CSS as possible, since in my experience it always runs smoother. Due to the large image, and the timed interval involved, using jQuery animation was not ideal in this situation.